# codeigniter do_upload not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to add a file upload function in my website using codeigniter's upload library.

here's my view file (display.php):

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="filename" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the controller:

```
public function testupload()
{
  if ( ! empty($_FILES))
  {
    echo 'start upload';
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/tempfile/';
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
    {
      echo 'error!';
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'success!';
    }
    echo 'end upload';
  }
  $this->load->view('display', $this->data);
}
```

but the code seems to stop after `$this->upload->initialize($config);` the file was not uploaded, and there was no message at all. only the `'start upload'` message appeared; the `echo 'success'` , `echo 'error'` , and `echo 'end upload'` do not appear.

why is that? can anyone help me??

Comment: use `$this->upload->display_errors()` to debug the errors

Comment: enable the debug mode. `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`  and print this one as well `$this->upload->display_errors()`;

Comment: nope. nothing is working. not even a simple `echo 'blabla';` worked if put after `$this->upload->do_upload('filename');` I tried @Naga 's advice but still nothing.

Comment: Your action is empty try `action="<?php echo base_url('controller/function');?>"` don't for get to autoload url helper

Comment: I thought if the action attribute is empty string, it will point to the same function? anyway, I tried putting the uploading part to another function but still the same. only the `start upload` message appeared, but nothing after that.

Comment: Instead of empty try isset

Comment: @wolfgang1983 if `empty` doesn't work then the `start upload` message should not have appeared. so that's not the problem

Comment: maybe fileinfo in php module doest active. you can see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42101982/7531626

Answer (score 1):

Late from party, but maybe this can help somebody with same problem. Please try this:

**Views**:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('test/upload');?>
    <input type="file" name="photo">
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**Controller**:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    function upload() {
        $config = array(
            'upload_path'  => './assets/upload/',
            'allowed_types'=> 'gif|jpg|png',
            'encrypt_name' => TRUE // Optional, you can add more options as need
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
            exit();
        } else {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($this->upload->data());
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside **views** i recomended use this function `form_open_multipart('ctrl/method')` but if you prefer using HTML5 forms, just be sure correct the attributes in form like this.

```
<form action="<?=site_url('ctrl/method')?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="file" name="photo">
</form>
```

More preferences in `$config['..']` can you find in documentation CodeIgniter [https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload#preferences)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this....

```
public function testupload()
{
  if ( ! empty($_FILES))
  {
    echo 'start upload';
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/tempfile/';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
    {
       $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('display', $error);  //loads the view display.php with error
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'success!';
    }
    echo 'end upload';
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $this->load->view('display', $data); //loads view display.php with data
  }

}
```

Comment: the same result.. after submit, it only displays `start upload` and nothing after that..

Comment: i think you have to set more `$config[]`..see here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: also check write permission on your uploading folder...problem may be due to this...

Comment: I checked using is_writable and it's writable. tried removing `!empty($_FILES)` condition and still the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/tempfile/';
```

to

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/tempfile/';
```

Comment: what is the different between `'./assets/img/tempfile/` and `'assets/img/tempfile/'`??

Answer (score 0):

i check this code this work perfect
simply add this line

```
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|gif|jpg|jpeg';
 $config['max_size']    = '7000';
```

after this

```
 $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/tempfile/';
```

or you can also set this in view page

```
action="<?php echo base_url('YourController/testupload');?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

this is due to php server version and it's option.

1).go to cpanel account

2).click "select php version", in the software section.

3).tap the "fileinfo" chexbox in the php option and save.

now you can upload file perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue as described. I have fixed it using the following: Open the file system/libraries/Upload.php go to function validate_upload_path() and add the command `return TRUE;` as a last line inside this function. Save and try again.

Answer (score 0):

use this for image upload:

```
  $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png');
  if ($_FILES['filename']['error'] == 0) {

        $img = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
        $tmp = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
         if (in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) {
            $path = "./assets/img/tempfile/" . strtolower($img);
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path)) {

                $_POST['filename'] = $path;

            }
        }
    }
```

use insert query to insert file :

```
       $this->db->insert('table_name', $_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem on macOS. It seems that if you are not the "main" user of your laptop/pc, the default permission is "Read Only". You must change it to "Read & Write".

1. Right click on the folder
2. Get Info
3. Sharing and permissions
4. Change 'Read Only' to 'Read & Write'

Answer (score 0):

add allowed file type parameter in config

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is missing the following,

```
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
```

Recorrect it by rewriting the above code.